# jquery Validate Casuing Initail invalid elements to become valid on second 'save' button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

So, I am trying to use jQuery Validate to check for duplicate values in a form, and it's working for the most part. However, I am getting the following weird behavior:

1. The user will enter a couple duplicate values, and click save
2. jQuery Validate will show 'Duplicate Name' in the UI for each of the duplicate values
   [image: First two invalid claims]
3. The user does not fix the duplicate values, but rather, adds another duplicate value
4. The user clicks save again, and the previous two invalid elements are marked valid, and the `Duplicate Name` message disappears, but the third value is correctly marked as invalid.
   [image: Third invalid claim without previous two marked as duplicate]
5. If the user clicks save again, then all three error messages are shown correctly.
   [image: All three correctly marked as duplicate]
6. If the user clicks on save without correcting any, the client-side validation is not followed and the server-side errors are shown for duplicate values.

Basically, I'm wondering what is wrong with my jQuery validation logic? Is it that I'm not forcing a revalidation every time the save button is clicked?

Here is my jQuery Validation code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkForDuplicateClaimName", function (value, element) {
    console.log('calling checkDuplicateClaimName')
    var customClaimForm = $("form.form-horizontal");
    var claimRepeated = 0;
    if (value != '') {
        var matchingClaims = 0;
        // Loop through the whole form to find duplicate claim names
        customClaimForm.children().each(function (count, item) {

            // Have to iterate through the custom claim div to find the names
            if ($(item).attr("id") === "custom-claims-div") {
                var customClaimDiv = $("#custom-claims-div");
                customClaimDiv.children().each(function (count, claim) {
                    var customClaimNameToCompare = $(claim).find('label').text();
                    if (value == customClaimNameToCompare) {
                        matchingClaims++;
                    }
                });
            }
            // Not the custom claim div, just the labels from the default scopes
            else {
                var nameToCompare = $(item).find('label').text();
                if ((value == nameToCompare)) {
                    matchingClaims++;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return matchingClaims === 1 || matchingClaims === 0;
}, "Duplicate Name");

$.validator.addClassRules("duplicateClaimName", {
    checkForDuplicateClaimName: true
});

var validate = $("form.form-horizontal").validate({
    ignore: "", // This checks hidden input values, which is what we want for the claim name validation
    errorElement: 'div',
    errorClass: 'custom-claim-validation-error',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo($(element).parent().find("#claim-name-lbl"))
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        console.log('calling submit handler');
        form.submit();
    }
});

$('form.form-horizontal').submit(function () {
    console.log('calling submit form');
    console.log(validate);
});
```

Here is the code for when a new claim is added to the `custom-claims-div`. It is the code that adds the class `duplicateClaimName` for jquery validation.

```
function oidc_addCustomProfileClaim() {

    // Grab the custom claim name and value
    var customAttName = $("#dialog-add-custom-scope-claim #customAttName").val();
    var customAttValue = $("#dialog-add-custom-scope-claim #customAttValue").val();

    // Get the last index of the custom claim div
    var lastId: number = -1;
    var div = $("#custom-claims-div");
    if ($("#custom-claims-div").children().length) {
        lastId = parseInt($("#custom-claims-div").children().last().attr("data-id"), 10);
    }
    lastId++;

    // Create the new form-group
    var newDiv = $("<div data-id=\"" + lastId + "\" id=\"claim-info-div\" class=\"form-group row\">");

    newDiv.append("<label data-id=\"" + lastId + "\" id=\"claim-name-lbl\" name=\"CustomClaims[" + lastId + "].ClaimLabel\" class=\"col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right\" style=\"padding-right: 10px! important;\" value=\"" + customAttName + "\">" + customAttName + "</label>");

    //Need to make a hidden input so that the model will be correctly filled when passed to the controller
    newDiv.append("<input data-id=\"" + lastId + "\" id=\"claim-value\" name=\"CustomClaims[" + lastId + "].ClaimValue\" type=\"text\" class=\"col-md-5\" value=\"" + customAttValue + "\" />")
    newDiv.append("<input id=\"hidden-claim-value\" name=\"CustomClaims[" + lastId + "].ClaimLabel\" class=\"duplicateClaimName\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + customAttName + "\" />")

    // Create the label for disabling/enabling the claim
    newDiv.append("<input data-id=\"" + lastId + "\" id=\"disable-claim-chkbx\" name=\"CustomClaims[" + lastId + "].IsDisabled\" style=\"margin-left: 75px;\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"false\"/>");

    // Create the Button
    var button = $("<button class=\"btn btn-xs btn-white btn-danger\" data-action=\"delete\" style=\"margin-left: 79px; width=80px;\" type=\"button\">");
    var deleteText = $("<i class=\"ace-icon fa fa-trash-o fa-lg\">");

    // Build the form group
    button.append(deleteText);
    button.append(" Delete");
    newDiv.append(button);

    div.append(newDiv);
}
```

This is the modal JS to add a new claim to the form:

```
$("#dialog-add-custom-scope-claim").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 420,
    title: "<div class=\"widget-header\">Add a new profile custom scope</div>",
    title_html: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Add",
            "class": "btn btn-primary btn-xs no-border",
            click: function () {
                oidc_addCustomProfileClaim();
                $('#new-claim-name-form').find('#customAttName').val('');
                $('#new-claim-value-form').find('#customAttValue').val('');
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            "class": "btn btn-xs no-border",
            click: function () {
                $('#new-claim-name-form').find('#customAttName').val('');
                $('#new-claim-value-form').find('#customAttValue').val('');
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The elements in question have the correct `duplicateClaimName` class in the HTML:

```
<input id="hidden-claim-value" name="CustomClaims[@i].ClaimLabel" type="hidden" class="duplicateClaimName" value="@Model.CustomClaims[i].ClaimLabel" />
```

Thanks in advance for any input!
Edit:

Here is the relevant HTML for my form submit button, if it helps:

```
 @using (Html.BeginFormWithCss("form-horizontal"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please, fix the following errors.", new { @class = "alert alert-block alert-danger no-style-list" })

    <h3 class="header smaller lighter green">Scope profile</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right">Name</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" data-auto="attributes" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" value="@Model.Name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right">FamilyName</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="FamilyName" name="FamilyName" type="text" data-auto="attributes" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" value="@Model.FamilyName" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="custom-claims-div" class="form-group">

        @if (@Model.CustomClaims.Count() > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < @Model.CustomClaims.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div data-id="@i" id="claim-info-div" class="form-group row">
                    <label data-id="@i" id="claim-name-lbl" name="CustomClaims[@i].ClaimLabel" class="col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right" style="padding-right: 10px !important;" value="@Model.CustomClaims[i].ClaimLabel">@Model.CustomClaims[i].ClaimLabel</label>

                    <input data-id="@i" id="claim-value" name="CustomClaims[@i].ClaimValue" type="text" data-auto="attributes" class="col-md-5" value="@Model.CustomClaims[i].ClaimValue" />
                    <input id="hidden-claim-value" name="CustomClaims[@i].ClaimLabel" type="hidden" value="@Model.CustomClaims[i].ClaimLabel" />

                    @if (Model.CustomClaims[i].IsDisabled)
                    {
                        <input data-id="@i" id="disable-claim-chkbx" name="CustomClaims[@i].IsDisabled" style="margin-left: 75px;" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input data-id="@i" id="disable-claim-chkbx" name="CustomClaims[@i].IsDisabled" style="margin-left: 75px;" type="checkbox" value="false" />
                    }

                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-white btn-danger" data-action="delete" style="margin-left: 75px;" type="button">
                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>

    <div id="dialog-add-custom-scope-claim" class=modal>
        <div>
            <div id="new-claim-name-form" class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Claim Name</label>
                <input id="customAttName" style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="text" value="" class="col-xs-12" placeholder="Claim Name" />
            </div>

            <div id="new-claim-value-form" class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Claim Value</label>
                <input id="customAttValue" type="text" value="" class="col-xs-12" placeholder="Claim Value (attribute name from FID)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix form-actions">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-9">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check fa-lg"></i>
                Save
            </button>

            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Index")">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
                Cancel
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: *"Is it that I'm not forcing a revalidation every time the save button is clicked?"* - yes, probably.  But we cannot see your HTML markup to know what kind of button and if it's really triggering anything or not.  Even if you had included the markup, tagging the question with HTML would only be for questions specifically about HTML markup.

Comment: Okay, I included the relevant HTML. I still want to know what's going on with my jQuery validate logic, and what might be causing my issue. :)

Comment: Your save button is triggering validation as long as it has the `type="submit"` attribute.  But seriously, without a minimally compilable working example, that's about all I can tell you.

Comment: What more else could I provide to you? I believeI have included all relevant code for my issue... ;\

Comment: *"What more else could I provide to you?"*  - You're missing enough markup for a complete working form.  I'd like to help you without having to reconstruct by blindly guessing.  Please see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, @Sparky. I would appreciate help. I thought I provided enough initially. I have added the HTML for my form and more JS to help, I hope.